# How to tell if memcache was flushed programatically?

Tags: memcached, memcache, php-memcached

How can I tell if memcache was flushed programatically?

If I issues a `echo flush_all | netcat localhost 11211` to memcache how can I tell it actually worked? I am writing some code to flush all servers and want to make sure they all received the command.

Comment: Mostly asking this because I didn't see any results in Google and I know I will come across this again in a year or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far it seems as one way to do it is to `echo stats | netcat localhost 11211` and look at `STAT cmd_flush` and see if the number has incremented.

`echo stats | netcat localhost 11211 | sed --silent '/cmd_flush/p'

I can then compare this and see if it changed.